# Warning at pod update due to difference in bit code settings in project and pods

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods, bitcode

I am trying to do a Pod update and recently started getting this error, request you to kindly help me what should I do.

I have tried the solution given for $inherited addition but no success yet.

```
[!] The `MYAPP_DEV [Debug]` target overrides the `ENABLE_BITCODE` build setting defined 
in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the 
CocoaPods installation
- Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
- Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The `MYAPP_DEV [Release]` target overrides the `ENABLE_BITCODE` build setting defined in 
`Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods.release.xcconfig'.
 This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `$(inherited)` like this in the Build Settings of your target:

[image]

(you have to select `Other` in the down menu to see the text box)